# Why is my shutter speed stuck while using mirror lockup?

Tags: canon, shutter-speed, mirror-lockup

On my Canon Mark II when I use mirror lockup my minimum shutter speed is always 1/30 of a sec but I need a much longer shutter speed, such as 30 of a sec. I have tried using manual mode, Av mode, and Tv mode but no matter what; the minimum shutter speed is always 1/30 of a sec.

Comment: Could you please state the Model number correctly? A Canon mark II could easily be one of 3 or more different cameras. Are you able to select different shutter speeds in normal Tv or M modes?

Comment: The minimum shutter speed available will be the *shortest* shutter speed. If you need a longer shutter speed than what the camera allows you are being limited by the *maximum* shutter speed. (e.g the Canon 5D Mark II has a minimum shutter speed of 1/8000 second and a maximum shutter speed of 30 seconds. Any longer and you must use *Bulb* mode)

Comment: Which camera? 1D Mark II? 1Ds Mark II (totally different FF camera than the APS-H 1D Mark II)? 5D Mark II? 7D Mark II?

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried using manual mode, Av mode, and Tv mode but no matter what; the minimum shutter speed is always 1/30 of a sec.

I'll bet you're just misreading the display. The display on most (maybe all) Canon DSLRs reads `30` for 1/30s exposure, and `30''` for 30s. 30s is the longest shutter speed setting that many cameras (including the Canon 5DmkII) will record; to get a longer exposure, you need to use bulb mode (B) and (usually) a remote shutter release. So, double check your camera and see if it's not actually reading 30s (again, `30''`) rather than 1/30 (`30` without the tick marks).